# Uninstalling GIT on windows

Tags: git, cygwin, uninstallation

I have had various msysgit installs on my windows vista laptop over the past year, using the "msysGit-fullinstall", "msysGit-netinstall" and "preview installers. Also, installed / used different versions along the way. I also had a GIT binary installed as part of my Cygwin package. I screwed up along the way (actually, I could not edit .gitconfig anymore), and decided to go nuclear and remove GIT to allow me the have a fresh install (which I can love a bit more :) ).

I tried the below steps, but still the build fails with the error "Old version git-* commands still remain in bindir" - when attempting to use the net installer.
- I removed GIT through Add / Remove programs in control 
- Removed all GIT files from usr/local/bin - and every other "*git*" file I could find
- I even removed my Cygwin enviorment
- My current %HOME% directory is empty

If I chose to install via the "preview" or "full" installers, it works, can I can use the GIT env / commands - except I again cannot edit the .gitconfig file, and get the error message:

"error: could not lock config file .git/config: No such file or directory"

In summary, I have a botched GIT windows env, so how can I clean it such that I can reinstall GIT!

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two steps that you have to do to manually "uninstall" git on Windows:

1. You have to remove all paths to your `bin` folders from your `PATH` environment variable
2. Remove folder where your git/Cygwin are installed.

After that you can install Cygwin-less `msysgit` from here: http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/list

Comment: Yea, I had already those steps done, but subsequent "net", "full" and "preview" installs all cause issues (as described above). Thanks.

Comment: If you remove them from PATH they will not interfere with new msysgit.

Comment: Thanks Sergey. I cannot see anything in my PATH environmental variable that would be "git-related".

Comment: Try opening the command line and typing ``git``. Can it be found?

Comment: No, it cannt (just to confirm, I'm running that command through DOS)

Comment: Then just go ahead and install ``msysgit``.

Comment: Installed again.. still get: "./check_bindir: line 9: `       echo "if test "$bindir" != "$gitexecdir" -a -x "$gitcmd"; then  echo;   echo "if test "$bindir" != "$gitexecdir" -a -x "$gitcmd"; then  echo You hav make: *** [install] Error 2"

Comment: i.e., installing "msysGit-fullinstall-1.8.3-preview20130601.exe"

Comment: The install? No. I'm just doubling clicking the downloaded file "msysGit-fullinstall-1.8.3-preview20130601.exe"

Comment: What says ``make --version``?

Comment: not sure what ur referring to... I'm gonna reinstall Cygwin, with GIT, and see if i can get that do work (including editing .gitconfig)> Ill accept answer now, and will check back later to see if u have any other suggestions. Thanks Sergey

Answer (score 2):

Here is my approach to this (**without** removing CygWin):

1. first, verify Git is installed by typing 'git status' from Cygwin64 Terminal.

Now... Run cygwin-1-7-33\setup-x86_64.exe (or any other cygwin version's setup.exe):

```
> Install from local directory.
> Took default installation Options:
  * Root Directory: C:\cygwin64
  * Install for: All Users
  * Default Text File Type: DOS
> Local Package Directory:
   ...\cygwin-1-7-33
> Select Packages:
  Leave as is ("+All <-> Install") for most, except for removing the 4 git packages:
    > Scroll down to Devel:
      > Check the Bin column of all packages that start with 'git-' 
        (by clicking the 'New' column) - change from 'Keep' to '**Uninstall**':
        - git: Fast Version Control System - core files
        - git-completion: Fast Version Control System - git bash completion
        - git-gui: Fast Version Control System - git-gui viewer
        - gitk: Fast Version Control System - gitk viewer               
> Create Icons:
  No to icon on destop and start menu. (it's already there)
```

Now, verify Git is NOT installed by typing 'git status' from Cygwin64 Terminal:

```
~/ws> -bash: git: command not found
```

Answer (score 1):

So I had to re-install Cygwin, with the git package selected. Simply could not get the msysgit to work. Initially, all git commands worked, except I STILL could not edit the .gitconfig file. This was solved by:

1. mkdir ~/.git
2. git config --global user.email "damo...@foo.com"